# Timezones Problems

Tags: 16.04, date, timezone

I have an issue with my time zone, when i use this command i can see the date:

```
$ timedatectl
```

and it shows me the next message:

```
Local time: Wed 2018-06-06 11:02:25 -04
  Universal time: Wed 2018-06-06 15:02:25 UTC
        RTC time: n/a
       Time zone: America/Caracas (-04, -0400)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

The Universal Time zone is different from my local time zone. I have a system working on php on this server that is getting the universal time zone and no the local, how can i fix the Universal time zone to set it as the local?

Im working on a OS Ubuntu 16.04

Ty for your help

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

This will set UTC as your local time zone.

Comment: I dont want switch my local time to the unverisal time, i want to switch the universal time to local time.

Comment: It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It doesn't make sense to set UTC wrongly. UTC is the same everywhere.